# How to retrieve Amazon Returned Item from MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

I try to get the returned items for every Orders, but unfortunately it dosen't seem to provide this kind of information from the Amazon Web Services.

```
            public GetOrderResponse InvokeGetOrder()
            {
                // Create a request.
                GetOrderRequest request = new GetOrderRequest();

                request.SellerId = sellerId;
                string mwsAuthToken = "";
                request.MWSAuthToken = mwsAuthToken;
                List<string> amazonOrderId = new List<string>();
                amazonOrderId.Add("106-5297482-5403402");
                request.AmazonOrderId = amazonOrderId;
                return this.client.GetOrder(request);
            }
```

The code above is to getting the Order Information for a specific Amazon Order ID.

Here is the result

```
<GetOrderResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
    <GetOrderResult>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                <AmazonOrderId>asdfasdf</AmazonOrderId>
                <SellerOrderId>asdfasdfas</SellerOrderId>
                <PurchaseDate>07/17/2014 10:39:34</PurchaseDate>
                <LastUpdateDate>07/17/2014 22:17:37</LastUpdateDate>
                <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
                <FulfillmentChannel>AFN</FulfillmentChannel>
                <SalesChannel>Amazon.com</SalesChannel>
                <ShipServiceLevel>SecondDay</ShipServiceLevel>
                <ShippingAddress>

                </ShippingAddress>
                <OrderTotal>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>53.18</Amount>
                </OrderTotal>
                <NumberOfItemsShipped>2</NumberOfItemsShipped>
                <NumberOfItemsUnshipped>0</NumberOfItemsUnshipped>
                <PaymentExecutionDetail />
                <PaymentMethod>Other</PaymentMethod>
                <MarketplaceId></MarketplaceId>
                <BuyerEmail></BuyerEmail>
                <BuyerName></BuyerName>
                <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>SecondDay</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
                <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
                <EarliestShipDate>07/17/2014 18:50:15</EarliestShipDate>
                <LatestShipDate>07/17/2014 18:50:15</LatestShipDate>
            </Order>
        </Orders>
    </GetOrderResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>asdfsadfasdfasdf</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</GetOrderResponse>
```

I know this order contains a returned item.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try scheduling the transaction report from seller central because you can not request using MWS and whenever this report is ready you can retrieve it using "`_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_`" which does includes returned or refunded orders.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keyur, I Test that And give you some news. Thanks again

Comment: I am pleased @Jean-Francois, can you rate my answer if possible Thank you.