# Amazon mws api, I changed order status to returned , But still getting Shipped from API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using amazon mws api, I am trying to get ORDER status of amazon order.
But It does not provide me the Returned Order status. It only provide a very few order statuses.

I am only getting following order status from amazon mws order api call.
[image]

**I need to know how Can I get the order status as returned?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have the same issue and found this :
[How to retrieve Amazon Returned Item from MWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870766/how-to-retrieve-amazon-returned-item-from-mws)
According to this we can't get status as "Returned" using MWS. :(